# Json в кастомный адаптер

Tags: java, android

Добрый день. Я получил ответ сервера передал его во фрагмент

```
 public void Okhhtp(){


        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://link")
                .build();
        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new

                             Callback() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onFailure (Call call, IOException e){
                                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Text loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 }

                                 @Override
                                 public void onResponse (Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                                     final String result = response.body().string();
                                     MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void run() {


                                             dialogF.setResult(result);
                                             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                         }

                                     });

                                 }

                             });


    }
```

Во фрагменте я его получил и отправил в адаптер но при запуске лист вью ничего не выдает.

```
 public void setResult(String result) {

        //JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        if (result != null) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("dialog");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject productObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    UpList.add(new DialogSaveData(
                            productObject.getString("avatar"),
                            productObject.getString("name"),

                            productObject.getString("text"),
                            productObject.getString("state")
                    ));

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            CastomDialog adapter = new CastomDialog(getActivity(), R.layout.castom_dialog_list, UpList);
            // присваиваем адаптер списку
            dialogList.setAdapter(adapter);


        }
    }
```

Я попробовал создать строку в которую вписал json

```
res = "{\"dialog\": [{\"name\": \"2\",\"avatar\": \"2",\"text\": \"2\",\"state\": \"0\"},]}";
```

и подсунул ее вместо result, все хорошо. Начал сравнивать что приходит с сервера и эту строку, они одинаковы но при этом json из result не парсится. 
Подскажите с чем это может быть связано?

код адаптера

```
public class CastomDialog extends ArrayAdapter<DialogSaveData> {
    ArrayList<DialogSaveData> products;
    Context context;
    int resorse;
    String decode, a;

    public CastomDialog(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List<DialogSaveData> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.products = products;
        this.context = context;
        this.resorse = resource;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.castom_dialog_list, null, true);

        }
        DialogSaveData product = getItem(position);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        Glide.with(context).load(product.getImage()).into(imageView);

        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        textView.setText(product.getName());

        TextView mess = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mess);

        a = product.getMess();
        //try {
           // decode = URLDecoder.decode(a, "UTF8");
        //} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
          //  e.printStackTrace();
       // }
        mess.setText(a);

        //String new1 = product.getState().replace("1","New");
        //String new0 = new1.replace("0","");
       // TextView state = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.state);
       // state.setText(new0);


        return convertView;

    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте вызвать `notifyDataSetChanged()` у адаптера.

Comment: нельзя разрешить данный метод. Это Фрагмент

Comment: Попробуйте trim() у result вызвать перед парсингом

Comment: Нет, это тоже не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Тебе в любом случае нужно дернуть адаптер. 
Может так? - dialogList.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
Если будет больше кода, смогу помочь.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() по прежнему подсвечивается .  Я вроде весь код дал

Comment: Добавь код адаптера.

Comment: Обновил  код вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Где то с 13 часов провозился и в итоге путем  проб, исключений я выяснил источник проблемы. Вообщем php файл который генерировал json подключался к бд. Что бы не вписывать пароль в каждый пхп файл я создал отдельный файл с паролем и именем пользователя и вставлял его. По непонятной мне причине, это и стало ошибкой. Я стер строку include bd.php и вставил ее содержимое, все заработало. Если кто знает почему так произошло, расскажите пожалуйста а то я в недопонимании.